# How do we fix the spring configuration check popups that come while importing projects?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-config

I am trying to clone a Java project and start working on it using IntelliJ. When I open the project in IDE, it gives me a pop up saying unmapped Spring configuration files are found.

> Please configure Spring facet or use 'Create Default Context' to add one including all unmapped files.

There seem to be many files which do not have a default context and I am not sure if I can select the default option of creating a default context.  Can we ignore these prompts from the IDE or is it something that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to be able to do within the IDE. If you do not address the warnings, it's likely that you will not be able to run the application or integration tests within the IDE. Also, the IDE will not be able to be as heplful as it otherwise might.

If you do decide to address the issue, [here's a link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html) to IntelliJ IDEA's (Ultimate Edition) Spring configuration documentation.

Good luck!

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want to disable the notifications:**

> IntelliJ > Settings > Notifications > Spring Configuration Check > Select: No
>   popup

[image]